# How to copy from volume mapped opt to image opt folder in docker?

Tags: docker

Assuming I have a docker image

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /opt
COPY localfile ../imagefile
```

I can create my docker image `docker build -t my-image .` and have my local `localfile` not the image as `../imagefile`.

I can also do this interactively by

1. Run `docker run -it --name my-container --volume=$(pwd):/opt --workdir=/opt openjdk:8-jdk-slim`
2. Then `cp localfile ../imagefile`
3. Then `exit`
4. Then create the image by running `docker commit my-container my-image`

Both produce the equivalent `my-image`.

However, if I change my Dockerfile to below

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /opt
COPY localfile imagefile
```

I can build the image using the `docker build -t my-image .`. However, I cannot `cp localfile imagefile`, because the `cp` will only copy the file to the original disk volume folder mapped to `opt` and not the image actual `opt` folder.

Is there a way still copy my file to the image `opt` folder (and not the local one), when my `opt` is mapped to the local folder?

Or another way of asking, is there equivalent `COPY` command I can use when I'm running the container interactively to create the image?

Comment: I think you are asking how to copy a file from your local to the container? If so you can use docker cp. The documentation can be found here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Comment: I can't use `docker cp` interactively.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your workflow.  If you're rebuilding your image with the updated file (a good idea) why are you mounting content over it; and if you're mounting content over it, why do you need to copy the file to elsewhere in the container filesystem space?

Comment: You raise a good question @DavidMaze. I can map it to a folder that is not exist in the container, and that would solve the entire problem. I'm just curious if I do map it to a folder that is already existing in the container, I wonder is there a way to move what I have from the local folder to the container original folder (e.g. opt). Just mainly to understand if such capability exist or it's not supported.

Comment: Since you can't unmount the volume without also deleting the container, that's kind of an academic question; there's no way to see the container filesystem you've hidden with the volume.  The only exception is `docker commit` and it's never really a best practice to use it, at all.

Comment: Good one @DavidMaze. Thanks for explaining it. That makes it clear for any volume mount to an existing container drive is something to be avoided then. That helps in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two important details around this question:

1. If you mount something into a Docker container (or for that matter on your Linux host), it hides whatever was in that directory before; you can't directly see or access it.
2. In Docker in particular, you can't change mounts without deleting and recreating the container, and thereby removing the container filesystem.

So on the one hand, you can't copy from a mounted volume to the container filesystem at the same location; on the other, even if you could, there's (almost) no way to see the contents of the filesystem.

(As you note, `docker commit` will create an image of the container filesystem, ignoring volumes, so that will see this.  Using `docker commit` isn't really a best practice, though; building images via Dockerfiles as you've shown and using `docker build` is almost always preferred.)

In general I've found volume mounts useful for three things, where hiding the container content is acceptable or even expected.  You can use mounts to inject config files into containers (where you want to overwrite the image's copy).  You can use mounts to read log files back out (where you don't care what the image started with).  If you have a stateful workload like a database, you can use a mount to hold the data that needs to be persisted (so it outlives the container filesystem).